# How to change the url pattern of user revisions?

Tags: users, nodes, path-aliases

How can i change the url pattern of a user revision ? I want to change

```
users/jon-doe/revisions/123/view
```

to

```
users/jon-doe/archive/123/view
```

There is no option in [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to influence the url patterns of revisions.

Answer (score 2):

This path is defined by revisions module [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), so if you want to alter it, use [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in your module.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Copy element to new path:
  $items['users/%/archive/%/view'] = $items['users/%/revisions/%/view'];

  // Optionally remove original - this may break some links!
  unset($items['users/%/revisions/%/view']);
}
```

And of course remember to clear the caches!

Comment: After the copy to the new $item you could modify $items['users/%/revisions/%/view'] so the callback does a redirect to the new path.

Comment: I actually had to do somtehing like this: $items['user/%user/revisions/%/view']  = $items['user/%user/archive/%/view'] ;